# Interpolation of variables inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: string, groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline, gstring

I am asking for help now because I have been struggling with a simple `sed` command to be called inside a Jenkinsfile that needs a little variable interpolation.

Better showing the command instead of a large explanation:

```
sh "sed -i -e 's/-RELEASE/-${unixEpoch}/g' myFile"
```

`sed` does not agree with this syntax and prints that the command `s/` is not finished.

I have read Groovy documentation about String and GString but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong ?

Any clues on this?

EDIT:

I am getting the `unixEpoch` by calling `date +%s` in order to get the current timestamp.

I printed the command just to be sure what's executed and I found:

```
sed -i -e 's/-RELEASE/-1525341883'
/g' myFile
```

The full error sent by `sed` is:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated 's' command`

I found weird that the printed command has an `\n` in the middle of it...

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on Ubuntu 16.04 with a `unixEpoch` value of `123456` (for testing). Can you share a bit more about how you are executing it?

Comment: @mkobit I added some more context. I think I found the solution. It seems that the command `date` is adding a new line at the end of the string causing `sed` to explode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date +%s` has a newline at the end, and when you interpolate it into your generated `sed` it is including that newline which explains why `sed` is complaining. You could do `${unixEpoch.trim()}` or trim the `unixEpoch` value before using it.

Comment: This is what I expected. Thanks a lot!